# Using Tags in Profile Page (About Me Description)

Tags: discussion, profile-page, network-profile

How can I use the Tags in Profile Description. I saw few StackOverflow friends using the TAGS in there Description page. Can some one tell me how can it be done? It will be nice for me to just simple click on the tags and check for new questions and answers!!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
[tag:your-tag-of-choice] Hello World!
```

Take a look at [comment markup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), it's listed there.

Also, if you're thinking of random names for tags, it only works with one word. So something like:

[tag:hello world] <-- will just show up as normal text

Where as:

[hello-world](/questions/tagged/hello-world) <-- works as expected

Answer (score 2):

[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) = `[tag:c++]`

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) = `[meta-tag:status-declined]`